# Posting score to Game Center leaderboards

Tags: swift, xcode6, game-center, gamekit, game-center-leaderboard

I am creating a game using swift on apple's Xcode 6 beta 6, and trying to add the high score of my game to gamecenter leader boards. I have created the leader boards in gamecenter.

So, how do I add my high score, which I saved as a NSUserDefault, to my gamecenter leader boards?

I tried using :

```
GKScore.reportScore([highScore], withCompletionHandler: nil)
```

but it just crashes. The initLeaderboard func has been deprecated in ios 8 so I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First you have to create the GKScore object.  Then you set the gkScore.value.  Finally, you report the score.

```
// if player is logged in to GC, then report the score
if GKLocalPlayer.localPlayer().authenticated {
    let gkScore = GKScore(leaderboardIdentifier: "leaderBoardID")
    gkScore.value = score
    GKScore.reportScores([gkScore], withCompletionHandler: ( { (error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            // handle error
            println("Error: " + error.localizedDescription);
        } else {
            println("Score reported: \(gkScore.value)")
        }
    }))
}
```

Comment: I implemented this, which is kinda the same as Jared Davidson's tutorial on YouTube but i noticed that my highscores are not being updated accordingly. The "All Time" remains super non-updated, do you know why? Thanks.

Comment: I haven't done anything with GameKit in a while.  However, I remember there being issues with sandbox accounts and the leaderboard.  Try using more than one sandbox account to test with.  Of course, make sure the leaderboardIdentifier is correct.

Comment: Thanks, it works now, after creating a new leaderboard it works perfectly fine!.

Answer (score 5):

### iOS 14+

In iOS 14 and above we should use:

```
/// Class method to submit a single score to multiple leaderboards
///   score - earned by the player
///   context - developer supplied metadata associated with the player's score
///   player - the player for whom this score is being submitted
///   leaderboardIDs - one or more leaderboard IDs defined in App Store Connect
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
open class func submitScore(_ score: Int, context: Int, player: GKPlayer, leaderboardIDs: [String], completionHandler: @escaping (Error?) -> Void)
```

Here is an example:

```
GKLeaderboard.submitScore(
    score,
    context: 0,
    player: GKLocalPlayer.local,
    leaderboardIDs: ["leaderboardID"]
) { error in
    print(error)
}
```

#### Async variant

The above API is compatible with Swift 5.5 concurrency. If you want your method to be **async** just use:

```
@available(iOS 14.0, *)
open class func submitScore(_ score: Int, context: Int, player: GKPlayer, leaderboardIDs: [String]) async throws
```

```
try await GKLeaderboard.submitScore(
    score,
    context: 0,
    player: GKLocalPlayer.local,
    leaderboardIDs: ["leaderboardID"]
)
```